# Medium size images with alpha

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

When answering a question, I've wanted to include large images that have an alpha channel, but not necessarily at their original size. When I append an `m` to the image URL to shrink it, the alpha channel disappears, and it looks ugly. Example:

**Original:** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAsYY.png`
[image]

**Shrunk:** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAsYYm.png`
[image]

Can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because imgur provides a jpeg for the smaller version (yes, it still has the `.png` extension, but don't let that fool you). Jpeg doesn't support an alpha channel, so imgur replaces it with a solid color.

The only way around this is to resize yourself and upload two pngs, then link them like this:

```
[![Blender logo](https://small/image.png)](https://large/image.png)
```

Example:

[image: Blender logo]

Comment: That wasn't the answer I was hoping for :-( , but thanks!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that despite compiling the posting images post years ago. Heh.